# Issues with structs c++

Tags: c++

So, I have a binary file which holds int values. So int takes 4 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;


class IntFile
{
public:
    //int index = 0;
    int value;
    FILE* file;
    IntFile() {}
    ~IntFile() {}
    int mnumbers[10];
    int mnumbers2[10];

    // get value from current index in file
    int getValue(int index)
    {
        fseek(file, 4*index, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&value, 4, 1, file);
        return value;
    }

    friend struct Move;
    struct Move
    {
        int index = 0;
        int value = 0;

        bool operator==(const Move&other) const
        {
            return index == other.index;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Move&other) const
        {
            return index!=other.index;
        }

        int &operator*()
        {
            return value = IntFile::getValue(int index); <- this thing does not work, I am getting errors like expected primary expressions..
        }
        Move&operator++()
        {
            this->index = index+1;
            return *this;

        }
        Move&operator--()
        {
            this->index = index -1;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    Move begin()
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        //index = 0;

    }
    Move end()
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        //index = 9;
    }
};



int main()
{
    IntFile file;
    int A;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        file.mnumbers2[i] = 0;
        cout << file.mnumbers2[i] << " "; // make every element of array = 0
    }


    file.file = fopen("text.txt", "r+b");

    for (IntFile::Move Iter = file.begin(); Iter != file.end(); ++Iter)
    {
        fread(file.mnumbers2,4,1,file.file);
        cout << " I " << endl;
        //cout << "Iterator: " << Iter;
    }

    cout << endl;
    A = file.getValue(5);
    cout << "A: " << A << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << file.mnumbers2[i] << " ";
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////
    fclose(file.file);
    return 0;
}
```

But I am not entering this loop

```
for (IntFile::Move Iter = file.begin(); Iter != file.end(); ++Iter)
    {
        fread(file.mnumbers2,4,1,file.file);
        cout << " I " << endl;
        //cout << "Iterator: " << Iter;
    }
```

In `begin()` we put cursor to the begging of the file, and at the end `end()`
cursor should be at the end of the file, obviously. My that does not work.
Is there any tips you can give me? I basically need some help with `operator*` and `begin(), end()`

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `begin` and `end`. Your compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: Are you the same OP from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528650/not-entering-the-loop-with-custom-iterator-c)?

Comment: When I see C++ code with static C-style arrays I smell trouble. Why can't things like `mnumbers` be `std::vector<int>` instead? This will avoid a whole lot of nasty surprises when your magical numbers aren't right.

Comment: Add `return` statements to the `begin()` and `end()` functions.   Without them, your loop has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter What should i return?

Comment: In both cases, an object of type `Move`.   To do that, both functions need to create an instance of `Move` (e.g. a local variable), set its members as needed, and return it.

Comment: std::fstream! It's C++!